# Pass argument from navHost (Compose) to ViewModel with Dagger-Hilt

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I have this on my NavHost:

```
composable(
    ScreenRoutes.AstronautDetailsScreen.route,
    arguments = listOf(navArgument("astronautId") { type = NavType.IntType })
) { backStackEntry ->
    backStackEntry.arguments?.let {
    AstronautDetailScreen(astronautDetailsViewModel)
  }
}
```

I want the viewModel to receive the `astronautId` so it can communicate with the useCase and send a GET request with this dinamic id.

In the viewModel I've got this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AstronautDetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    astronautDetailsUseCase: AstronautDetailsUseCase,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    private val argument = checkNotNull(savedStateHandle.get<Int>("astronautId"))

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _astronautDetails.value = astronautDetailsUseCase(argument)
        }
    }
```

The screen that I go to is this:

```
@Composable
fun AstronautDetailScreen(astronautDetailsViewModel: AstronautDetailsViewModel) {

    val astronautDetails by astronautDetailsViewModel.astronautDetails.observeAsState(AstronautDetails())
```

But it always says that `argument` is null and crashes.
Can someone tell me please what could I'm be doing incorrectly?

Comment: This seems you are passing viewModel object to AstronautDetailScreen in navHost instead of injecting by hiltViewModel(). How about changing your composable function to inject the viewModel by hilt? As like AstronautDetailScreen(astronautDetailsViewModel: AstronautDetailsViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {}

Comment: Yes bro! this was the solution. I don't know hoy to mark it as the correct answer but thanks so much

Comment: I'm reposting it as an answer so that other people can get direct answer of it in Google search instead of reading the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `NavHost`, you are passing viewModel object to `AstronautDetailScreen` instead of injecting it by `hiltViewModel()`. 
You can change your composable function to inject the viewModel by hilt. In that way, your arguments will be available in `SavedStateHandle` of your view model class. You can change your composable function like below:

```
AstronautDetailScreen(
    astronautDetailsViewModel: AstronautDetailsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    // Your rest of the code here
  }
```

Or, if you want to pass your view model instance from NavHost instead of default value of the composable function, Then you can modify your NavHost part like below:

```
composable(
    ScreenRoutes.AstronautDetailsScreen.route,
    arguments = listOf(navArgument("astronautId") { type = NavType.IntType })
) { backStackEntry ->
    backStackEntry.arguments?.let {
    val astronautDetailsViewModel: AstronautDetailsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    AstronautDetailScreen(astronautDetailsViewModel)
  }
}
```